# Overriding attributes in GLSL

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

Newer versions of GLSL reduce the amount of standard, built-in attributes and uniforms, e.g. `gl_Color` and `gl_ModelViewMatrix` are not in GLES 2.0.

Is it OK to override these names and redefine them in a shader to be of another variable type?  Would declaring your own `gl_ModelViewMatrix` uniform when running on an early GLSL version work if you set them yourself?

In early GLSL `gl_Color` can be per-vertex or for a whole call, depending on if the client called `glColor()` or `glColorPointer()` - can you set an attribute once so it in effect becomes a uniform?  Or how to deal with this ambiguity?

<sub>(This is all in a quest to make shaders that work across a range of targets with some simple find-replace scripts at load-time)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override them and you can't use variables-names with the beginning "gl_"( A paper told me this ). Changing build-in types/variables is afik not possible at all.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't find the papers, but i'm sure this is correct.

Comment: The OpenGL-3 core and GLSL 1.40 standards clearly state that custom variables must not be named with a 'gl_' prefix. Once can however use a bit of preprocessor trickery to apparently "reintroduce" them.

Comment: @datenwolf yes that was my plan, although i'm a bit stuck with gl_Color

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, if you want to easily support multiple versions of GLSL, is to use macros.  For example, you could define your input color as:

```
#ifndef color
in vec4 color;
#endif
```

Then, to run on an older version of GLSL, you prepend the shader with `#define color gl_Color`